# How to deploy spree to amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, spree

I'm currently considering deploying my Spree website to Amazon EC2. I searched online and bumped into capistrano and bitnami. Bitnami says that its a Cloud Hosting and manages the Amazon Cloud. Does this mean I'll be needing some kind of hosting company to use Amazone EC2? I'm still not comfortable with whole Amazon EC2 yet. Can I just consider it as another hosting company, which I can use domain and upload my website? Or does it only deals with database?

I would like to know some of the best options/process in deploying a Spree website to Amazon EC2? and some simple guidelines to achieve the result. This is my first time deploying a website other than deploying to heroku by following the tutorials, so please understand if my questions are not smart and somewhat obvious. I've bumped into a bunch of documents but they're still confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about this: http://bitnami.com/stack/spree/cloud/amazon . The only difference is that the bitnami amazon image already has `Spree` installed in it. Whereas if you start from a blank EC2 image/instance you are going to have to install spree yourself (i.e install the Rails application, with the database, etc)

Bitnami also offers and alternative solution hosted on AWS/Azure http://bitnami.com/stack/spree/cloud . This is the easiest/fastest solution since they do all the installation deployment for you. Once you deploy you can manage the Spree application from their console. However, if you are the hacker kind, this option provides less flexibility if you want to tweak little things in the backend of the `Spree` application.